# Faster fetching data from View or Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

hi we have a stored procedure which is scheduled for daily basis that fetches records from a table having huge data after filtering. my question is if i create a view on the table and fetch the data from the view will this be faster process or slower?

Answer (score 6):

A standard view, it shouldn't make any difference as the inner SQL just gets expanded out into the query. Note, the same applies with **inline** table-valued user defined functions (think "parameterised view").

However, if you make it an [indexed view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx), then you could see a performance improvement.

Answer (score 3):

Just remember, a view is nothing but a select statement (indexed views are different). If you have:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

And that is in a procedure, if you put the same thing in a view and then did:

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW
```

Within a procedure, there is absolutely no difference between these two. But, if things get more complicated so that you're joining against a lot of tables, then it really depends on how they're being accessed.

For example, if you create a view that accesses 6 tables and then you write a query that only needs to pull data from 3 of those tables, you may benefit from a process called simplification that takes place within the optimization process and you'll see a plan that only references 3 tables. However, you might not. If not, then a query that you would write against the 3 tables will generally run faster than a plan against a view that accesses more than 3 tables.

If you start nesting views, having views that call views or join to views, then you may see a very serious performance degradation.

In general, if you're working with stored procedures, I would suggest you just write your queries against the tables directly. It won't hurt performance at all, and it could help you avoid issues with nested views and plan simplification.

Answer (score 0):

just complementing @AdaTheDev answer:

```
the same applies with table-valued user defined functions
```

that's true for inline table-valued functions, but not 100% true for a multistatement table-valued function. This second type of function will use a lot more resources (memory) than the first one

About the index view, it can help, but bear in mind that it can drastically will increase your storage space

Comment: Good catch, I did indeed mean inline UDF! I'll update my answer as that is a very important point